# How to execute Selenium 2 tests in Jenkins

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, junit

- I would like to be able to use Selenium 2 with Jenkins.
- I am new to both so please excuse any of my ignorance.
- I noticed the following plugin for jenkins [HERE](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin), and installed it.
- I have a base class as follows:

  ```
  public class BaseTestClass {

  protected Properties myprops;
  protected String baseurl;
  protected WebDriver driver;
  protected boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  protected StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  public BaseTestClass()
  {
      try
      {
          myprops = TestUtil.readProps("src/MyProps.properties");
          baseurl = myprops.getProperty("baseurl");

          driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.fireFox());
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }       
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
      driver.quit();
      String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
      if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
      }
  }

  protected boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
      try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
      } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    protected String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
      try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
          alert.accept();
        } else {
          alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alert.getText();
      } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
      }
    }
  ```

I have the following configuration on the **Selenium Plugin** for **Jenkins** :

[image]

..

[image]

Once I try to build the project and run a Junit selenium test in Jenkins, it builds successfully, but the test it self fails. (works fine when running with ant from the command line - and changing the `WebDriver` to :
 `driver = new FirefoxDriver();`) - Using selenium RC

This is the console output in Jenkins: 
[image]

**EDIT**: I just noticed you can Archive the Junit .xml output file after the build in Jenkins. I am getting a class not found exception? This is weird because like i said, it builds just fine when using `ant` from the command line.

The error is as follows:

```
<error message="com.loggedin.CCBreadCrumb" type="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException">
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.loggedin.CCBreadCrumb at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
</error>
```

Thanks in advance for any direction or help you may have!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i was making several mistakes. To resolve the `Class Not Found Exception` I added the following to ant's `build.xml` - (remember I am new Ant)

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >       
    <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="bin" classpathref="SeleniumCC.classpath"/>
</target>
```

This got my java classes compiling.

Then I had to update the selenium standalone server to the latest version (`selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.x.jar`) This is located in:

`jenkins_home_directory\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib`

Last I was trying to use the wrong configuration in the selenium plug-in (I was trying to use a Custom RC node configuration, what I needed was a Custom web driver node configuration.)

[image]

ALSO NOTE : When running Selenium Server on Red Hat I had to setup and install XVFB with Jenkins Xvfb plugin.

I hope this can be of help to others in the future! Good luck!

Comment: I too had a problem while integrating Selenium 2 + Jenkins. I am able to run my selenium test in jenkins. But i am not able to launch the browser through jenkins. It runs like headless browser. May i know weather it is possible to do it? If yes please share how to do it. Please share if you have nice tutorials.

Comment: Yes I was able to do it with firefox on both a MAC OSX 10.8.3 and Windows 7. You must use a custom web driver node configuration as I stated above and it should launch the broswer if you have set up a selenium grid with firefox configured. I could not find any good tutorials on this. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well if your intention is to simply run the selenium script without Selenium Grid. Then you do not need any plugin. You would only need remote webdriver.

To launch Selenium 2 from Jenkins the best way would be is to wrap the test process in the pom.xml (if you are using Maven) and then simply create a new job in Maven using "Build a maven2/3 project" in Jenkins.

Comment: I would like to use Selenium Grid, and no it is not a Maven project.

Comment: Change this line `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());` to `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());` and try

Comment: Changing the port to 5555 does not work, and im sorry that was an old screen shot where i had IE as a configuration, i updated that screen shot in the original question.

Comment: So then change `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());` to `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"),  DesiredCapabilities.firefox());` Also if it does not work please share the error message.